# How do I prove $F_*Z=(Z^i\circ F^{-1})\partial_i'$, where Z is a field, and $(F(U),x\circ F^{-1})$ a chart with coordinate fields $\partial_i'$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

I am teaching myself differential geometry on manifolds with some notes a professor gave me.
As an initial calculation to prove that the  Levi Civita connection is invariant under isometries, the notes threw the following result \eqref{push} leaving it as an exercise which I have been scratching my head about:

**Let $F:M \to M'$ be a diffeomorphism and $Z$ be a vector field over $M$. The field $F_*Z$ over $M'$ is defined putting $(F_*Z)_{F(p)} = F_{*p}Z_p$. For example, if $(U,x)$ is a chart of $M$ we have that $x_* \partial_i = D_i$, partial derivative with respect to the variable.
More in general, if the transformed chart $(F(U),x\circ F^{-1})$ of $M'$ has coordinate fields $\partial_i'$ we have that $F_*\partial_i=\partial_i'$ and
\begin{equation}\label{push}
\tag{$\sharp$}
F_*Z=F_*(Z^i\partial_i)=(Z^i\circ F^{-1})\partial_i'.
\end{equation}**

Therefore Z is differentiable , because $F_*Z$ is differentiable

**Note: $x_*$ is the pushforward map**

**My try:**

I know the pushforward of a differentiable function $f$ between manifolds, $f_*$ is supposed to map tangent vector of one space to tangent vectors of the other one and it is defined as $(f_*\nu)h = \nu (h \circ f)$ when $\nu$ is a derivation and $h$ a smooth function, I don't know if that is useful but it took me nowhere, so I was trying to do something like  :

$(F_*Z)h =Z (h \circ F)=Z^i \partial_i (h \circ F) $

and then I was hoping to find "(the expresion I want)h", so no idea where that $F^{-1}$ in \eqref{push} is coming from.

**Can someone please show me the proof of \eqref{push}? Please be as detailed as posible, I am new at manipulating the pushforward map.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you started on the right path: work from $(F_*Z)(h)$ using the definition.

First, some notation: fix a system of local coordinates ${\bf x}=(x^1,\dots,x^n):U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ on the open set $U\subset M$, and let instead ${\bf y}={\bf x}\circ F^{-1}$ be the coordinates on the open set $U'=F(U)\subset M'$.

By definition, for every $h\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M',\mathbb{R})$ and every $p\in M$ we have
\begin{equation}\label{def}
\tag{1}
(F_*Z)_{F(p)}(h)=Z_p(h\circ F).
\end{equation}
We use this definition to prove the formula you are interested in. In our local coordinate systems, \eqref{def} reads, for $q=F(p)$
\begin{equation}\label{def_coords}
\tag{2}
(F_*Z)^i(q)\,\partial_{y^i}h(q)=Z^j(p)\,\partial_{x^j}(h\circ F)(p).
\end{equation}
Apply the chain rule to compute the derivative on the RHS of \eqref{def_coords}:
\begin{equation}
Z^j(p)\,\partial_{x^j}(h\circ F)(p)=Z^j(p)\,\partial_{y^k}h(q)\,\partial_{x^j}F^k(p)
\end{equation}
where $F^k(p)$ is the $k$th component of $F(p)$ in the coordinate system ${\bf y}$, i.e. $y^k(F(p))$. By definition of $y$, the $k$th component of ${\bf y}(F(p))$ is the $k$th component of ${\bf x}(p)$, so $\partial_{x^j}F^k(p)=\delta_j^k$.

Then, we can rewrite \eqref{def_coords} as
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
(F_*Z)^i(q)\,\partial_{y^i}h(q)=Z^j(p)\,\partial_{y^k}h(q)\,\partial_{x^j}F^k(p)=\\=Z^j(p)\,\partial_{y^j}h(q)=Z^j(F^{-1}(q))\,\partial_{y^j}h(q)
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
which is precisely what we were looking for: as $h$ was arbitrary
\begin{equation}
F_*Z=Z^j\circ F^{-1}\,\partial_{y^j}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I am not sure about this part :"Recall however that ${\bf y}$ is defined precisely as $F({\bf x})$, so $\partial_{x^j}F({\bf x})^k=\delta_j^k$". I think that would be true if it were: $\partial_{x^j}F({\bf x})^k=\partial_{x^j}x^k=\delta_j^k$ or   $\partial_{y^j}F({\bf x})^k=\partial_{y^j}y^k=\delta_j^k$. Instead we have the derivative of $y^k$ with respect to $x^k$ ??

Comment: If $y=F(x)$, the k-th component of $F(x)$ is $y^k$, I don't get why can't I just plug it in :$\partial_{x^j}F(x)^k=\partial_{x^j}y^k$

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what the misunderstanding might be. let me edit my answer.

Comment: It's better now, I think I get it. What I was missing is that the k-th component of the POINT $F(p)$ is the assigned coordinate $y^k(F(p))$ so  $y^k(F(p))= (x^k\circ F^{-1})(F(p))=x^k(F^{-1}\circ F(p))=x^k(p)$. But I was trying to get the k-th component of the function F

Comment: Yes, I am afraid I had not chosen the best possible notation at first. Sorry about that! Anyway, I hope this was helpful!

Comment: It was, thank you. Just like in the notes I should be using that $y=x \circ F^{-1}$, but this means the chart is the same for M or M', In general one takes one different chart for each manifold, why should we be taking the same chart here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136432/discussion-between-johnny-lemmon-and-j-c-vegao).